# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid constant pool index 63

Tags: java, pool

I tried to extract a .class File from the .jar, and it worked, but then I changed something an now i got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid constant pool index 63
```

Here's my code:

```
String path = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
if (path.endsWith("."))
    path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

File file = new File(decodedPath + (decodedPath.endsWith("\\") ? "Classfile.class" : "\\Classfile.class"));

InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(FileSync.class.getResourceAsStream("/Classfile.class"));
FileWriter write = new FileWriter(file);

int c;
while ((i = read.read()) > -1) {
    write.write(i);
}
write.flush();
read.close();
write.close();

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\java.exe", "Classfile", decodedPath + (decodedPath.endsWith("\\") ? "Program.jar" : "\\Program.jar"));
builder.directory(file.getParentFile());
Process process = builder.start();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: When and where do u see this error?

Comment: When i run this code above, just nothing happens, and process.exitValue() is 1...
When I try to run this exact .class file that my program extracted from the jar, it gets the error...
but the file seems alright, it has the same size as the original file in the jar! When I extract the class file normally from the .jar it works perfect!

Comment: What deterred you from simple running ProcessBuilder with `java -cp xxx.jar yyy.Zzz.class`? Don't you have problems with file/class name, embedded classes, references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputStreamReader` and `FileWriter` does implicit bytes <-> char conversion. Since java class files are binary files, use the raw bytes via `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

Probably, you can use a hex editor and open the class files before and after writing to verify what is missing/added in the new class file.

Comment: Like this?
`InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(FileSync.class.getResourceAsStream("/Classfile.class"));
OutputStreamWriter write = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));`

Comment: Any java.io class with Reader/Writer suffix in its name, does bytes <-> char conversion (by default using platform's character encoding). Instead of above try this:

`InputStream read = FileSync.class.getResourceAsStream("/Classfile.class"); 

OutputStream write = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Comment: That's probably right. The character conversion replaces unknown characters with a question mark ('?', ASCII-code 63), which explains the reference to constant pool index 63.

Comment: So this should work:
`InputStream in = FileSync.class.getResourceAsStream("/Updater.class");   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);`